# How can I match two different data columns in excel based on date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have two different sheets, each with two columns.

In Sheet 1, Column A lists every date over the last two years, and Column B lists average humidity measurements for those dates.

In Sheet 2, Column C lists sporadic dates over the last two years on which a specific event occurred, and Column D lists the number of times the event occurred on each of those dates.

I'd like to move the data in Column D into a column in Sheet 1 based on the dates. How can I go about this?

Sheet 1:
[image: Example of Sheet 1:]

Sheet 2:
[image: Example of Sheet 2:]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser . It would be helpful if you can put a sample of how your sheet looks with data and what you want it to look like (I know it sounds simple to visiualize since you see the sheet... but for someone that doesn't it might not.)

Comment: You need to see if the date cell formats are the same. If so, then a VLOOKUP should work just fine. If you have mismatch formats between sheets (such as one is date and other text), then you'll need to convert the cell format in the sheet or within the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to do.

In Sheet1 `C1` enter the formula and drag down the whole column:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!C:D,2,FALSE)
```

To improve it a little bit (that for dates that have nothing in Sheet2 it should remain empty instead of saying #N/A) do:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!C:D,2,FALSE),"")
```

What this does:

- `=VLOOKUP(A1,` Looks for the value of `A1` in `Sheet1` (the date from the full list)
- `Sheet2!C:D,` Looks for it in the first column range of `C:D` in `Sheet2` (that's the dates of the limited list)
- `2,` When a (date) match is found, it brings back the value of the 2nd column in (which is the number of events in column `D`)
- `FALSE)` Only when the match (of the date) is an exact match and not simply the closest date match